# React native IOS build issue

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I installed Xcode from AppStore and started the project with `react-native init IOS_project` command. I had an error after running npm run ios and I opened `.../IOS_project/ios/IOS_project.xcodeproj` file with Xcode and started the build. Build was failed with the error

fatal error: module map file `/Users/artemgorovoi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/IOS_project-distoubdwfsutrcrzcjxmzmcwzfx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap` not found

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWx5U.jpg
https://tinyjpg.com/web/output/rt2x4mgj3tgk8607dy3q0ad6utw2ep1m/94D33C31-0A82-406D-B07F-299E0F621023.png

Comment: Try a clean `Command` + `Shift` + `K`

Answer (score 0):

this happens because in order to run your React Native project through Xcode you must open the `.xcworkspace` file, in your case `IOS_project.xcworkspace`, if you only open the `.xcodeproj` file Xcode won't be able to locate your Pods